# Bound of Fourier transfrom of a cutoff function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I am reading an article, I found that 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\chi_{[0,t_0]}(s)
\end{align}
is bounded by $\sqrt{1+s^2}^{-1}.$ I do not know how to get this ?

Comment: Calling it a cuntion isn't very nice.

Comment: I am sorry I made a mistake, " cuntion" should be "function".

Comment: Sorry, @Post No Bills,$\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform, I made a typo. $\sqrt{1+s^2}$ should be replaced by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}.$

Comment: @Post No Bills, this comes from P.13 the equation (7.1) of the article "Resonant decompositions and the I-method for cubic nonlinear Schrodinger on R^2"[arXiv:0704.2730](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2730)

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform of $1_{[0,t_0]}$ is related to the [sinc function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function), which is continuous and bounded by a multiple of $|s|^{-1}$. Any such function is bounded by a multiple of $(1+s^2)^{-1/2}$ for all $s$.

Details: 
$$ \hat 1_{[0,t_0]}(s) = \int_0^{t_0} e^{-ist}\,dt=\frac{1}{is}(1-e^{-ist_0})$$ 
The right-hand side is continuous (including $s=0$). Its absolute value is at most $2/|s|$. Hence, the function
$$ \hat 1_{[0,t_0]}(s)\sqrt{1+s^2}$$
is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and bounded at infinity. Let $M$ be its supremum. We have 
$$\hat 1_{[0,t_0]}(s)\le \frac{M}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}$$
In the paper, the constant $M$ is hidden in $\lesssim$.